# Multiple Regression Coefficient output

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I am a University student running an analysis of data collected during a field trip.

The goal of this analysis is to determine whether the length and species of a limpet are good predictors of where on a rock the limpet may be found (variable = *height*).

I have run a multiple regression on R, using the model:

`limpets.2 <- lm(height ~ length + species, data = limpets)`

The response variable *height* is continuous, as is the predictor variable *length*.
The predictor variable *species* is a factor with three levels for the three species. *Co*, *Cr* and *Cd*.

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = height ~ length + species, data = limpets)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-73.190 -23.358  -0.449  18.919 102.919 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 126.3523     4.8989  25.792  < 2e-16 ***
length       -1.6840     0.1446 -11.644  < 2e-16 ***
speciesCo     6.0416     3.0087   2.008  0.04494 *  
speciesCr   -12.6376     3.8076  -3.319  0.00094 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 32.14 on 889 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2554,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2529 
F-statistic: 101.7 on 3 and 889 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

My question is, while R has given the coefficients of *Co* and *Cr*, where do I find the coefficient for *Cd*?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just gets 'absorbed' into the intercept term. It turns out that to represent a factor with $n$ levels, you need $n-1$ 'dummy' variables in your regression equation. In your case, species has levels Co, Cr and Cd, so $n = 3$. This means you need $n - 1 = 2$ dummy variables. Using these two dummy variables, you can represent your factor, species, like this

- Cd: $x_0 = x_1  = 0$,
- Co: $x_0 = 1, x_1  = 0$ and,
- Cr: $x_0 = 0, x_1  = 1$

Comment: would this mean that my model equation; "height = 126.35 + (-1.684 length) + (6.042 speciesCo) + (12.638 speciesCr)"    is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right